# Change child animation/transition on parent hover

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

**What I am trying to achieve:**
I am trying to change a child CSS animation when hovering the parent. It is, however, for some reason not working.

**Explanation:**
*.front-ball* has the *hvr-wobble-vertical* applied to it from the start. I then want the animation to change to *.front-ball* scale animation when hovering it's parent element, *.wbutton*.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="wbutton img-responsive center-block" role="button">
  <img class="front-logo" src="img/logos/logowork_03.png" />
  <img class="front-ball" src="img/logos/logowork_09.png" />
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wbutton:hover > .front-ball {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.front-ball {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-wobble-vertical;
  animation-name: hvr-wobble-vertical;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-wobble-vertical {
  16.65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(8px);
    transform: translateY(8px);
  }
  33.3% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
    transform: translateY(-6px);
  }
  49.95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px);
  }
  66.6% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
    transform: translateY(-2px);
  }
  83.25% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
    transform: translateY(1px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-wobble-vertical {
  16.65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(8px);
    transform: translateY(8px);
  }
  33.3% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
    transform: translateY(-6px);
  }
  49.95% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px);
  }
  66.6% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
    transform: translateY(-2px);
  }
  83.25% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
    transform: translateY(1px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

It is obvious that I am trying to use 2 animations/transitions at a time, but I do not know what the correct way to reach my desired effect is.

Comment: you want to change this hvr-wobble-vertical animation to scale on hover, or you want to apply both on hover?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that wasn't very clear. I want to go from hvr-wobble-vertical to scale on hover. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make another `keyframes` to handle the `scale animation` and on hover replace the `hvr-wobble-vertical`   with your new keyframes

```
.wbutton:hover > .front-ball {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-animation-name: hve-scale;
  animation-name: hve-scale;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hve-scale {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes hve-scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yb1LrL5o/